# Docker Images hosting in private repositories in our own servers

Tags: docker

I am working in a multinational company and i am looking for a way/solution so that i can use our own cloud/repositories to host docker images.We can not host docker images of our code build on docker public or private repositories,i understand private repositories are only accessible by me but still my org dont want to host code outside org.
So is there any way or we can set up repositories in our own servers which are not accessible outside world ?

Comment: you can set up gitlab at one of our machine and use it as docker registry https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/container_registry.html

Comment: I recently answered a very [similar question on DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/8239/host-a-docker-registry-native/8241#8241) and gave several possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The [docker registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/) has an [open API](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/) that has been implemented by lots of vendors. Docker includes a [registry image](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry) that is open source and you can run yourself. Here's an example command:

```
docker run -d --restart=unless-stopped --name registry \
  -e "REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY=/var/lib/registry" \
  -v "registry-data:/var/lib/registry" \
  -p "5000:5000" \
  registry:2
```

Note that this is just the bare server, and doesn't do any authentication, authorization, or TLS encryption without more configuration.

Answer (score 1):

you can install [Harbor](https://goharbor.io/) (a private docker registry) in your company owned servers. It's open source and  CNCF project.